# Adding Visual Studio Code binary to the path in Mac, Command not found, although it is in the $PATH

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, path

I want to open Visual Studio Code with the terminal by writing code. 
I wrote the following line in the bash_profile

```
export PATH="/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:$PATH"
```

So that the PATH is updated with directory where the binary code is.

Unfortunately, I still get:

`tommasos-mbp:~ tommaso$ code
-bash: code: command not found`

The weird thing is that the PATH have been correctly updated, indeed if a run in the terminal `env`, I get:

PATH=/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:

Also if I run directly in the terminal

```
/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code
```

Visual studio code opens perfectly.

What is wrong here?

Comment: I did restart the terminal. Indeed If I run env I get the new path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lose the double-quotes around your export (the path is escaped, so you don't need them). Otherwise the terminal literally interprets your path as being /Applications/Visual\ Studio ...

```
export PATH="/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:$PATH"
```

Should be:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Just to make sure that I understood correctly, if leave the double quotes my path is "/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin (with quotes)?

Comment: If you want to use quotes you won't want to escape the path, so PATH="/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:$PATH" would work. If you escape the string though and put it in quotes it will have the backslashes included, which you don't want. Escaping allows you not to use quotes around the string, the opposite would be using quotes allowing you not to escape a string.

Comment: Try this in Terminal and you'll see the difference `echo "escaped\ with\ quotes"; echo escaped\ without\ quotes`.

Comment: I just added another tightly related question, you may know as well the answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59627014/difference-between-escape-strings-and-raw-strings

Answer (score 5):

In case there is new Mac user like me, there is a build-in option in vscode where it will automatically add vscode in the PATH environment variable so that you can access `code` through Terminal. Follow this [Launching vscode from terminal in Mac OS documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line)

[image]