# Difference between escape strings and raw strings?

Tags: escaping, rawstring

In Computer Science is there any difference between a raw string and an escaped string?

For me these two terms appears to be synonym, it means that all the symbols in the string will be treated a literal characters.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can think of a raw string as a "string literal", meaning what is defined in this way is literally what you should get. Different languages define raw strings in similar ways, while others don't. An escaped string uses "escaping" (such as backslashes) to indicate special treatment for the succeeding character. `bash` in particular uses quotes and double-quotes in very specific ways. If you want to learn how `bash` treats strings in quotes and without [here's a fairly comprehensive look](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).

Comment: Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character